# dedicated thread for io_service::run()

Tags: c++, concurrency, boost-asio

I want to provide a global `io_service` that is driven by one global thread.  Simple enough, I just have the thread body call `io_service::run()`.  However, that doesn't work as `run` (`run_one`, `poll`, `poll_one`) return if there is no work to do.  But, if the thread repeatedly calls run(), it will busy loop when there is nothing to do.

I'm looking for a way to get the thread to block while there isn't any work to be done in the io_service.  I could add a global event to the mix for the thread to block on.  However, that would require users of the `io_service` to notify the event every time they used the service.  Not the ideal solution.

Note: there are no actual globals and I never use events for concurrency  I just simplified the problem down to my exact need.  The real goal is a `asio::deadline_timer` subclass that doesn't require an `io_service` as a construction parameter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to create an `io_service::work` object.

See this section of the documentation:

[Stopping the io_service from running out of work](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.stopping_the_io_service_from_running_out_of_work)

Comment: Did not know about this one. +1, and deleted my hack-ishy suggestion.

Comment: thanks, I had started to make timer with and infinity timeout just for this purpose.  I am perpetually impressed with asio.  They missed very few corner cases.